New tag for questions concerning mining reward structure
Lately (and for the past 10+ years) there have been many debates over the shift from block subsidy to transaction fees as the main part of block rewards, and how that impacts Bitcoin's security. Current questions that touch on this topic are variosly tagged with any combination of mining-reward, reward-schedule, transaction-fees, mining-theory, economic-theory and even future-proof.
Given that there is currently no tag specifically for this topic and it's not obvious what its name should be, I wanted to open a discussion first before I go and start retagging.
Notably, these two tags don't exist yet: reward-structure and security-budget. I'm slightly in favor of the latter for the use case described above, but there are surely other options I haven't thought of yet. Or maybe I'm wrong and this topic doesn't need its own tag (though I suspect this is a topic that will only become more prominent over time).

Also related is [tag:blockspace-market], still thinking about an answer.

I think the new tag you propose might have a bit of an overlap with mining-reward and blockspace-market especially, but I agree that it is an interesting sub-topic that we could group. I like security-budget since it emphasizes the role of the mining reward as an incentive to thwart attacks.
